# .sifr-active, visibility: hidden; not working in Safari 4.0.2?

Tags: css, flash, sifr

I trying to hide the element before replacement by using the .sIFR-active class, set on the HTML element, to apply CSS rules to elements when sIFR is active. I set the visibility: hidden; and it is working fine in IE and Firefox. Not Safari.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you provide an example page? What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Oh, think I might have the solution, see answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```
.sIFR-alternate {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thnks a lot. This is nice workaround that simulates visibility:colapse for Safari!!

Answer (score 0):

The `.sIFR-active` class might be set on *either* the `<html>` or the `<body>` element. If your CSS rule is explicitly `html.sIFR-active` it won't trigger if it happens to be added to the `<body>`.